# How do you move the earth to the left side of the screen in Google Earth Pro?

Tags: google-earth-pro

I've looked at the mouse and keyboard shortcuts to navigate in Google Earth Pro. Perhaps I'm missing something really simple. I'm creating an animation and want the entire earth to be on the left third side of the screen instead of the middle.

I saw [a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K5i6tjtVDkA) that had the earth on the left side. So this must be possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That video was mostly created in Google Earth Studio, an online tool for video creators that gives more control over the camera view, and exports video frames ready for post processing in video editor software. They may have done those effects in that software.

In Earth Pro, you can do something similar with the earth at the top or the bottom of the map window by holding down the CTRL key and moving the up/down arrows to title the camera view up/down.  Ctrl & left/right rotates the heading, so won't quite get you what you want.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was hoping Google Earth Pro could do the same. I just got access to Earth Studio and will try to move the earth over.